# Proxy object - when should I use them in fact

Tags: magento2, object-manager, object, proxy

I have yesterday read great tutorial about Proxy objects:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_proxy_objects/

I understand that I should use them to lazy load object which have can be slowly loaded, so for example:

- they have a lot of dependencies by themselves
- they make a complex db query
- they have a lot of code lines?
- for objects, which won't be used in every class class (for example if class

Are there any practical advices when they really should be used or where they shouldn't. Do anyone has any good practices. For me it seems it is good to declare most of classes as lazy loaded, juz in case, but I bet it is not a good idea.